# Filtering a list by removing unwanted values in Scala

Tags: scala, list

Being a beginner in Scala, I stumbled upon a problem I can't seem to resolve. Basically, I'm given coordinates from a file that I managed to add to a List, then sort all those values into different lists like shown bellow:

```
List(List(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67), List(21, 23, 25, 26, 27))
```

By using this code:

```
val lines = io.Source.fromFile("in.txt").getLines

val coordinates =
  lines
    .drop(0)
    .toList
    .sortWith(_<_)
    .mkString
    .replaceAll("\\s", "")
    .grouped(2)
    .toList

val conditions = 1 to 5000

val que = coordinates.map(_.toInt)

val thisIsIt = conditions.foldLeft(List():List[List[Int]])((acc, elem) =>
  que
    .filter(_.toString.startsWith(elem.toString))::acc)
    .filterNot(_.isEmpty)
    .filter(_.length > 3)
    .map(_.toList)
```

What I have to do is find the coordinates in each list that would follow the same pattern. For example, in the list

```
List(21, 23, 25, 26, 27)
```

I would like to remove the element "26", since the difference between adjacent values should be "2".

```
23-21 = 2
25-23 = 2
26-25 = 1,
```

But if we check the difference between the next element after 26, and the previous element 25, we can see that:

```
27-25 = 2
```

So if 26 is removed, the condition that the difference between each 
    adjacent values should be "2" becomes true,
    giving us the list

```
List(21, 23, 25, 27)
```

The other list that is:

```
List(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67)
```

should just return the same list, because the difference between elements is constant and it's "1".

In the end I should be given back the list

```
List(List(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67), List(21, 23, 25, 27))
```

I'll give another example with the list

```
List(31, 32, 33, 36, 37)
```

Although the difference between the first 3 elements is indeed "1" and the same can be said about the difference between the last 2 elements, there's no way to traverse from the beginning of the list to the end of it with a constant difference between values.

The coordinates can change and the number of values in each list can also change. Any help would be appreciated, since I'm dead in my tracks. I've tried using functions that use *head* and *tail*, iterating through the list and applying conditions, but nothing really seems to work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you please list out the patterns in list that you want to wish to have

Comment: What do you mean "there's no way to traverse from the beginning of the list to the end of it with a constant difference between values."? Of course, there is! Just remove the last two elements. Or first three.

Comment: @ChaitanyaWaikar that's the thing, the pattern really depends on the values that are in the list. The main goal is to find a pattern, with which you could traverse the list from beginning to end, but the pattern has to be static.

Comment: @Dima , that would work, yes, but the task I'm given requires me to check whether it's possible to traverse the whole list using some sort of pattern, if it's not possible, then it should just return an empty list.

Comment: @gibepesos your first  example removes an  element from the list ... If that's what you call "traverse using some sort of pattern", then that's the same exact thing I suggested you do in the last case - just remove two last elements, and then everything that remains is `_ + 1`

Comment: @gibepesos first of all what will be the value of that constant difference how we will get to know what we need to search for? in first list you are looking for 2 and in the next for 1.

Comment: @Dima Basically, the task is that multiple frogs are jumping across a field, and the coordinates I've provided are places where they landed. Each frog has a set distance they can jump, but they have to jump across the whole field. In the case of the last list, it's not possible that the same frog jumped across the field by landing in those exact coordinates, thus making the list unusable. The first list works, because due to the fact that the jump distance is 2 units, it can just jump over the coordinate that has a difference of 1. I hope this clarified things.

Comment: @RamanMishra I was thinking that it starts off with 1 and checks if that difference applies to all the values. If that's not the case, we use 2, and check if that difference applies to all values. If there's a case where this does not apply, we check if the difference of "2" holds true if we take the next value and do the same calculation, if it comes back true, we move forward the list, if it comes back false, it should just return a blank list. The comment above explains the task I have to do.

Comment: Instead of removing a value to fit a pattern, what about adjusting a value? Example: `2,4,6,9,10,12` Change the `9` to `8`?

Comment: @jwvh That wouldn't work in this case, as by doing so it would ignore the coordinates that I read from the file. I can't make any modifications with the values themselves, I can only try to see if there's a set pattern with which I can traverse the list.

Comment: @gibepesos in that case, the last example works if you remove the three elements in the middle: if the "jump distance" is 6, you can jump directly from 31 to 37. In fact, _any_ list will work that way: just remove everything except first and last elements

Comment: @Dima I wish that were the case, but I forgot to mention that in order for it to be a viable "jumping path", the list has to have at least have 3 elements that satisfy some sort of pattern.

Comment: @gibepesos that's the point. You "forgot to mention" a lot of stuff. Your problem is way underspecified (with your latest addition, the solution with removing the last two elements from the list still fits). I think, you need to give it a little more thought, and just rewrite your question.

Comment: @Dima Thanks for the input, I'll try to be more specific when rewriting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like maybe you just want to reduce each `List[Int]` to only those elements (if any) that are equidistant, beginning to end inclusive.

Here's my take on it.

```
val input = List(List(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67)
               , List(31, 32, 33, 36, 37)
               , List(21, 23, 25, 26, 27)
               , List(2, 12, 19, 22, 36))

val result = input.map{ lst =>
  val hd = lst.head
  val end = lst.last
  val distance = end - hd
  Stream.from(1).take(distance/2).flatMap{ step =>
    val rng = hd to end by step
    if (distance%step == 0 && rng.diff(lst).isEmpty)
      Some(rng.toList)
    else None
  }.headOption.getOrElse(Nil)
}
//result: List[List[Int]] = List(List(61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67)
//                             , List()
//                             , List(21, 23, 25, 27)
//                             , List(2, 19, 36))
```

Note: This assumes every `List[Int]` is ordered, or at least the `.last` is assumed to be greater than the `.head`.

Comment: Perfect, this is exactly what I was looking for, and yes, your assumption that every `List[Int]` is ordered was correct!

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if I understand what you are trying to do. Here is what I *think* you might mean: find the longest possible sublist of a given list, containing at least three elements of the original list, including the first and the last ones, such that the distance between each consecutive elements is constant.

In that case, here is a simple solution. 
Basically, first you find out all possible distances (by subtracting head of the list from each element, and keeping those values, that are positive, but not greater than half the distance between head and tail of the list), and then you try to construct the resulting sublist for each of those distances.

```
  def findIt(list: List[Int]) = {
    @tailrec def doIt(
      list: List[Int],
      candidates: List[Int],
      last: Int 
    ): Option[List[Int]] = candidates match {
       case Nil => None
       case dist :: rest => 
         val result = list.foldLeft[List[Int]](Nil) {
           case (Nil, x) => List(x)
           case (l@(head :: _), x) if x == head + dist => x :: l
           case (l, _) => l
         }
         if(result.head == last) Some(result.reverse) 
         else doIt(list, rest, last)
    }

    val candidates = list.foldLeft[List[Int]](Nil) { 
       case (Nil, x) => List(0)
       case (l, x) => (x - list.head) :: l
    }
    if(list.nonEmpty) doIt(
     list, 
     candidates.filter(x => x > 0 && x <= candidates.head/2).reverse, 
     list.head + candidates.head
    ) else None
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, this works, and in the end your figured out exactly what I was looking for! Thank you a bunch!